# Payment methods in France

Tags: payments, payment-gateway, ecommerce

I want to expand my webshops to France. I'm currently researching the payment methods in France. I'm not sure where to find this information, therefor I'm asking this question.

What I want to know:

- Which methods are used?
- How frequently are those methods used?
- What are the alternatives to creditcard methods?

I hope someone is willing to answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the nature of your webshop and the goods you are offering. France tends to be Credit Card, PayPal and Carte-Blue heavy.

- Credit Card (MasterCard, AmEx)
- [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/fr/webapps/mpp/merchant)
- [Carte-Blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carte_Bleue) (Debit Card)
- SEPA Direct Debit
- Bank Transfer
- Invoice

Mostly in that order.

Source: [here](http://ecommercenews.eu/the-most-common-payment-methods-in-europe/), [here](http://ecommercenews.eu/online-payment-methods-in-europe/) and [here](http://addons.prestashop.com/en/content/35-the-most-popular-online-payment-methods-by-country)

Comment: Thank you. How is Carte-Blue different than Credit Card? And what options are not vulnerable to fraud?

Comment: It's not a credit card, but a debit card. It's somehow like an Electronic Cash (EC) card in Germany. They are tied to the card holder's bank account and only allow transfers up to their bank's limit i believe. There are some more caveats to it though. In regards to fraud, define fraut. You need to accept that *all* electronic payment systems are vulnerable to fraud in some way. Most, if not all, payment systems allow the client to cancel payments.